# How was this distributed? (Trig equations)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How did this: $2(1-\sin^2x)=1+\sin x$

Become this: $2\sin^2x+\sin x-1=0$

Wouldn't it be: $2 -2\sin^2x-1+\sin x=0 ?$

Comment: No. In what you write, it should be $-\sin x$ (notice the minus sign), since you push this from the right-hand side to the left-hand side. Also, 2-1=1, and if you change sign of the whole equation, you recover the equation on 2nd line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start with $$2(1 - \sin^2(x)) = 1 + \sin(x) $$

Distributing, we have $$2 - 2\sin^2(x) = 1 + \sin(x)$$

Moving everything to the left side, we have $$(2-1) - 2\sin^2(x) - \sin(x) = 0$$

Multiplying by negative 1, we have $$2\sin^2(x) + \sin(x) -1 = 0$$

Hope that helps. If not, try to identify the point of confusion - we'll go from there. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I understand it now. Thanks to everyone else as well.

Answer (score 1):

You lost a sign when you moved $\sin x$ to the other side.  They actually put everything on the right.  If you fix the sign on $\sin x$, combine the $1$ and $2$, and multiply through by $-1$ your are there.